# Responsive hero treatment with top and bottom borders that extend on left side

Tags: css

I'm trying to code this hero treatment.

[image: Hero text treatment]

The title and paragraph text is contained to a grid that has a max-width of 1200px and auto left and right margins.

The top and bottom borders should come from the left edge, but stop at the end of the centered 1200px text box.

[image]

I've coded them as HRs thinking that may be more helpful to style.

```
<div class="hero">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x800" alt="">
    <div class="hero-text">
        <hr>
        <div class="contain-to-grid">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget laoreet dolor. Etiam quis leo venenatis, suscipit nisi id, luctus urna. Aenean iaculis justo vel consectetur mollis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget laoreet dolor. Etiam quis leo venenatis, suscipit nisi id, luctus urna. Aenean iaculis justo vel consectetur mollis.</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my CSS (this is currently just making the HRs go full-width)

```
    .hero {position: relative;}
    .hero img {width: 100%; height: auto;}
    .hero-text {position: absolute; bottom: 30px; width: 100%;}
    .hero-text hr {border-color: #000; margin: 30px 0;}
    .contain-to-grid {width: 100%; max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

I'm stumped. Any ideas on how to code this? It does need to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Just added '.inner' div and added css. Hope this help you.

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
}

.hero img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.hero-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero-text hr {
  border-color: #000;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.contain-to-grid {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600x800" alt="">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <div class="contain-to-grid">
      <div class="inner">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget laoreet dolor. Etiam quis leo venenatis, suscipit nisi id, luctus urna. Aenean iaculis justo vel consectetur mollis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget
          laoreet dolor. Etiam quis leo venenatis, suscipit nisi id, luctus urna. Aenean iaculis justo vel consectetur mollis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but it looks like the borders are not extending to the left side.

Comment: you want extent the left border?

Comment: Yes, like in the first photo